# Terraform - Can't use Firebase Management API with service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have run into an issue with importing an existing firebase into my terraform project.

Currently I'm using a infra project with a service account that has various admin, IAM and service account permissions (more than neccesary). This service account is used in both `google` and `google-beta` providers as the `impersonate_service_account` property.

I've enabled the firebase API on both the target project and infra project, and tried adding firebase permissions to the SA at the project level but for some reason I still encounter the API disabled error.

```
Error when reading or editing FirebaseProject: <firebase project id> googleapi: Error 403: Firebase Management API has not been used in project <project id> before or it is disabled. 
Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebase.googleapis.com/overview?project=<project id> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

The resource is defined as this:

```
resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
  provider = google-beta
  project  = google_project.project.project_id

  depends_on = [google_project_service.project_services["firebase.googleapis.com"]]
}
```

The APIs are enabled using a `for_each`:

```
resource "google_project_service" "project_services" {
  for_each                   = local.services
  project                    = google_project.project.project_id  
  service                    = each.value
  disable_on_destroy         = false
  disable_dependent_services = false
}


locals {
  services           = toset(concat(local.activate_apis))

  activate_apis = [
    "appengine.googleapis.com",
    ...
    "firebase.googleapis.com",
    ...
    ]
}
```

I'm sure there's a missing step, but has so far eluded me..

Comment: Can you add the resource you set it to depend on?

Comment: @MarkoE Updated with the api resources

Comment: You need to have `provider = google-beta` in both resources, at least documentation says so: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/firebase_project#example-usage---firebase-project-basic.

Comment: Hi, Can you check if the APIs are enabled on Google Cloud Console?

Comment: @MarkoE Hmm, I did try using up a `data` resource for the google-project with google-beta,  and tried on the google_project_services too but no luck.. 

Comment: @ZeenathSN Yep they definitely are enabled, on both infra and target projects

Comment: So you don't have a `google_project` created with `provider = google-beta`?

Comment: @MarkoE No - just the normal provider. It should create the same resource though..?!

Comment: Not really familiar with GCP terraform provider, but if I understand the way it works, if some of the features are available only in beta, then I don't think they will be available in the project created with a provider that is not in beta. But I might be talking BS. :)